# How can I convert a "char" to "std::string"?

Tags: c++, c, string, char

I'm trying to find **how to convert a *char* array into a *std::string***, but I can't find anything to do this.

If it is impossible, **could you explain me how can I read an std::string but by *scanf()* and *gets()* I can't**.

Best regards.

Comment: So much wrong in this question! `gets()`?!?!

Comment: Honestly, why the downvotes? He could be a little more specific, but this isn't a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of making a string from a character array is using a constructor that takes a pointer and the length, like this:

```
char charArray[] = {'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
std:string s(&charArray[1], 2); // s is "xy"
//                ^         ^
//                |         |
//    Pointer to the        |
//    starting position   Length
```